# How do I write SQL to fetch strings that begin with % in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle-database

Could someone please assist on how to fetch the data in SQL for all the strings starting with `%%string`?

I tried below to escape `%%` but it didn't work

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE host LIKE ‘[%][%]%’
```

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm) says you need to escape them with `{}` or `\`. So your example should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE host LIKE ‘\%\%%’;
```

You could also try some select strings to see what gets escaped:

```
SELECT '\%{%%}' FROM dual;
```